# How to calculate time difference with previous row of a data.frame by group

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

The problem I am trying to solve is that I have a data frame with a sorted POSIXct variable in it. Each row is categorized and I want to get the time differences between each row for each level and add that data back into a new variable. The reproducible problem is as below.
The below function is just for creating sample data with random times 
for the purpose of this question.

```
random.time <- function(N, start, end) {
  st <- as.POSIXct(start)
  en <- as.POSIXct(end)
  dt <- as.numeric(difftime(en, st, unit="sec"))
  ev <- sort(runif(N, 0, dt))
  rt <- st + ev
  return(rt)
}
```

The code for simulating the problem is as below:

```
set.seed(123)
category <- sample(LETTERS[1:5], 20, replace=TRUE)
randtime <- random.time(20, '2015/06/01 08:00:00', '2015/06/01 18:00:00')
df <- data.frame(category, randtime)
```

The expected resulting data frame  is as below:

```
>category randtime timediff (secs)
>A  2015-06-01 09:05:00 0
>A  2015-06-01 09:06:30 90
>A  2015-06-01 09:10:00 210
>B  2015-06-01 10:18:58 0
>B  2015-06-01 10:19:58 60
>C  2015-06-01 08:14:00 0
>C  2015-06-01 08:16:30 150
```

Each subgroup in the output will have the first row with timediff value of 0 as there is no previous row. I was able to group by category and call the following function to calculate the differences but could not get it to collate the final output for all category groups.

```
getTimeDiff <- function(x) {
  no_rows <- nrow(x)
  if(no_rows > 1) {
    for(i in 2:no_rows) {
      t <- x[i, "randtime"] - x[i-1, "randtime"]
    }
  }
}
```

I have been at this for two days now without luck so would greatly appreciate any help. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 29):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  arrange(category, randtime) %>%
  group_by(category) %>%
  mutate(diff = randtime - lag(randtime),
         diff_secs = as.numeric(diff, units = 'secs'))

#   category            randtime             diff   diff_secs
#     (fctr)              (time)           (dfft)       (dbl)
# 1        A 2015-06-01 11:10:54         NA hours          NA
# 2        A 2015-06-01 15:35:04   4.402785 hours   15850.027
# 3        A 2015-06-01 17:01:22   1.438395 hours    5178.222
# 4        B 2015-06-01 08:14:46         NA hours          NA
# 5        B 2015-06-01 16:53:43 518.955379 hours 1868239.364
# 6        B 2015-06-01 17:37:48  44.090950 hours  158727.420
```

You may also want to add `replace(is.na(.), 0)` to the chain.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. This solves it partly in arranging the output as required. However the lag() returns the previous row's time as the timediff value and not the actual difference.

Answer (score 21):

In base R you can use:

```
# creating an ordered data.frame
df <- data.frame(category, randtime)
df <- df[order(df$category, df$randtime),]

# calculating the timedifference
# option 1:
df$tdiff <- unlist(tapply(df$randtime, INDEX = df$category,
                          FUN = function(x) c(0, `units<-`(diff(x), "secs"))))
# option 2:
df$tdiff <- unlist(tapply(df$randtime, INDEX = df$category,
                          FUN = function(x) c(0, diff(as.numeric(x)))))
```

which gives:

> ```
> > df
>    category            randtime      tdiff
> 6         A 2015-06-01 11:10:54     0.0000
> 15        A 2015-06-01 15:35:04 15850.0271
> 18        A 2015-06-01 17:01:22  5178.2223
> 1         B 2015-06-01 08:14:46     0.0000
> 17        B 2015-06-01 16:53:43 31137.3227
> 19        B 2015-06-01 17:37:48  2645.4570
> 3         C 2015-06-01 10:09:50     0.0000
> 7         C 2015-06-01 12:46:40  9409.9693
> 9         C 2015-06-01 13:56:29  4188.4578
> 10        C 2015-06-01 14:24:18  1669.1326
> 12        C 2015-06-01 14:54:25  1807.1447
> 14        C 2015-06-01 15:05:07   641.7068
> 2         D 2015-06-01 09:28:16     0.0000
> 13        D 2015-06-01 14:55:40 19644.8313
> 4         E 2015-06-01 10:18:58     0.0000
> 5         E 2015-06-01 10:53:29  2071.2223
> 8         E 2015-06-01 13:26:26  9176.6263
> 11        E 2015-06-01 14:33:25  4019.0319
> 16        E 2015-06-01 15:57:16  5031.4183
> 20        E 2015-06-01 17:56:33  7156.8849
> ```

If you want minutes or hours, you can use `"mins"` or `"hours"` instead of `"secs"`.

---

An alternative with the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
# creating an ordered/keyed data.table
dt <- data.table(category, randtime, key = c("category", "randtime"))

# calculating the timedifference
# option 1:
dt[, tdiff := difftime(randtime, shift(randtime, fill=randtime[1L]), units="secs"), by=category]
# option 2:
dt[, tdiff := c(0, `units<-`(diff(randtime), "secs")), by = category]
# option 3:
dt[ , test := c(0, diff(as.numeric(randtime))), category]
```

which results in:

> ```
> > dt
>     category            randtime           tdiff
>  1:        A 2015-06-01 11:10:54     0.0000 secs
>  2:        A 2015-06-01 15:35:04 15850.0271 secs
>  3:        A 2015-06-01 17:01:22  5178.2223 secs
>  4:        B 2015-06-01 08:14:46     0.0000 secs
>  5:        B 2015-06-01 16:53:43 31137.3227 secs
>  6:        B 2015-06-01 17:37:48  2645.4570 secs
>  7:        C 2015-06-01 10:09:50     0.0000 secs
>  8:        C 2015-06-01 12:46:40  9409.9693 secs
>  9:        C 2015-06-01 13:56:29  4188.4578 secs
> 10:        C 2015-06-01 14:24:18  1669.1326 secs
> 11:        C 2015-06-01 14:54:25  1807.1447 secs
> 12:        C 2015-06-01 15:05:07   641.7068 secs
> 13:        D 2015-06-01 09:28:16     0.0000 secs
> 14:        D 2015-06-01 14:55:40 19644.8313 secs
> 15:        E 2015-06-01 10:18:58     0.0000 secs
> 16:        E 2015-06-01 10:53:29  2071.2223 secs
> 17:        E 2015-06-01 13:26:26  9176.6263 secs
> 18:        E 2015-06-01 14:33:25  4019.0319 secs
> 19:        E 2015-06-01 15:57:16  5031.4183 secs
> 20:        E 2015-06-01 17:56:33  7156.8849 secs
> ```

Comment: Yes, both these solutions work great. Thanks a lot, all of you.

Comment: @Mntester extended the answer with a base R solution

Comment: Wish I could have more than one upvote, such a nice, clean `data.table` solution! Note use `first_removed <- dt[dt[, -.I[1], by = category]$V1]` to remove the first row per category from the resulting data.table if needed (in my case I'm using the difference as a feature, so I don't want the zeros).

Comment: @Bar Another option to remove the first observation by group is `dt[, tail(.SD, -1), by = category]`, but on very large datasets the `.I` method wins on performance ([see here for a benchmark](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34753260/2204410)).

Comment: To me this is easier to understand `dt[ , test:=c(0, diff(as.numeric(randtime))), category]`.  I don't know how anyone could think of that `<-units()` trick. I'm impressed, but it's sad that you had to resort to that.

Comment: @geneorama Agreed on that. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Jaap Thanks a lot Jaap, how could we use this if we have another binomial variable for `by` to process(along with category) - which is a toggle status for the time column and we'd need to sum the total time using this toggle column only - by differencing the successive toggles first and then adding cumulatively.

Comment: @KeyshovBorate I'm not completely sure what you mean. Maybe post as a new question? You could link back to this one. Also make sure to include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610)

Comment: @Jaap Sure, here it is, Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51118608/calculating-conditional-cumulative-time-in-r