# Calculating conditional cumulative time

Tags: r, dplyr, difftime

Following the pointers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32999460/how-to-calculate-time-difference-with-previous-row-of-a-data-frame-by-group).

I'd like to calculate the cumulative time for *all* the `Cat`s, by considering their respective last toggle status.

`EDIT:`
I'd also want to check if the FIRST `Toggle` status of a `Cat` is `Off` and if it is so, for that specific `cat`, the time from midnight `00:00:00` till this first FIRST Off time should be added to its total conditional cumulative ontime.

Sample data:

```
       Time Cat Toggle
1  05:12:09  36 On
2  05:12:12 26R Off # First Toggle of this Cat happens to be Off, Condition met
3  05:12:15 26R On
4  05:12:16 26R Off
5  05:12:18  99 Off # Condition met
6  05:12:18  99 On
7  05:12:24  36 Off
8  05:12:26  36 On
9  05:12:29  80 Off # Condition met
10 05:12:30  99 Off
11 05:12:31  95 Off # Condition met
12 05:12:32  36 Off
```

Desired sample output:

```
  Cat Time(Secs)
1 36  21
2 26R 18733 # (=1+18732), 18732 secs to be added = total Sec from midnight till 05:12:12
3 99  18750 # (=12+18738), 18738 secs to be added = total Sec from midnight till 05:12:18
4 ..  ..
```

Any sort of help is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @camille Created a list of lists (dataframes) for all the cats, but as there's no specific sequence of toggles, things didn't work out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution using [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table):

```
# load the 'data.table'-package, convert 'df' to a 'data.table'
# and 'Time'-column to a time-format
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Time := as.ITime(Time)]

# calculate the time-difference
df[, .(time.diff = sum((shift(Time, type = 'lead') - Time) * (Toggle == 'On'), na.rm = TRUE))
   , by = Cat]
```

which gives:

> ```
>    Cat time.diff
> 1:  36        21
> 2: 26R         1
> 3:  99        12
> 4:  80         0
> 5:  95         0
> ```

---

In respons to your question in the comments, you could do:

```
# create a new data.table with midnigth times for the categories where
# the first 'Toggle' is on "Off"
df0 <- df[, .I[first(Toggle) == "Off"], by = Cat
          ][, .(Time = as.ITime("00:00:00"), Cat = unique(Cat), Toggle = "On")]

# bind that to the original data.table; order on 'Cat' and 'Time'
# and then do the same calculation
rbind(df, df0)[order(Cat, Time)
               ][, .(time.diff = sum((shift(Time, type = 'lead') - Time) * (Toggle == 'On'), na.rm = TRUE))
                                 , by = Cat]
```

which gives:

> ```
>    Cat time.diff
> 1: 26R     18733
> 2:  36        21
> 3:  80     18749
> 4:  95     18751
> 5:  99     18750
> ```

---

An alternative with base R (only original question):

```
df$Time <- as.POSIXct(df$Time, format = "%H:%M:%S")

stack(sapply(split(df, df$Cat),
             function(x) sum(diff(x[["Time"]]) * (head(x[["Toggle"]],-1) == 'On'))))
```

which gives:

> ```
>   values ind
> 1      1 26R
> 2     21  36
> 3      0  80
> 4      0  95
> 5     12  99
> ```

---

Or with the [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse) (only original question):

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  mutate(Time = lubridate::hms(Time)) %>% 
  group_by(Cat) %>% 
  summarise(time.diff = sum(diff(Time) * (head(Toggle, -1) == 'On'),
                            na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thanks Jaap. While creating `time.diff`, how could I check if the First `Toggle` for the `Cat` is `Off` and if so how could I add 'time from midnight to its First Off time'.

Comment: @KeyshovBorate Do you mean that for `Cat == 26R` the first `Toggle` has to be set to `On` and the corresponding `Time` to zero? Could you include the desired output based on above example data?

Comment: Sure let me add. No. It's basically adding the time from midnight for all the `Cat`s which has its Very First toggle as `Off` - Because that's going to be the first time it has been off since midnight - the time which we must consider as its total ontime.

Comment: Great to know Jaap :)

Answer (score 2):

One can use `as.difftime` function to convert time from `H:M:S` format to seconds. Then for each `On` statue find the `lead` record in order to calculate interval of time lapsed from `On`.

```
library(dplyr)

# Convert Time in seconds.
df %>% mutate(Time = as.difftime(Time, units = "secs")) %>%
  group_by(Cat) %>%
  mutate(TimeInterVal = ifelse(Toggle == "On", (lead(Time) - Time), 0)) %>%
  summarise(TimeInterVal = sum(TimeInterVal))


# # A tibble: 5 x 2
#   Cat   TimeInterVal
#   <chr>        <dbl>
# 1 26R           1.00
# 2 36           21.0 
# 3 80            0   
# 4 95            0   
# 5 99           12.0
```

**Note:** On can consider arranging data on `Time` ensure rows are ordered on time.

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text ="
Time Cat Toggle
1  05:12:09  36 On
2  05:12:12 26R Off
3  05:12:15 26R On
4  05:12:16 26R Off
5  05:12:18  99 Off
6  05:12:18  99 On
7  05:12:24  36 Off
8  05:12:26  36 On
9  05:12:29  80 Off
10 05:12:30  99 Off
11 05:12:31  95 Off
12 05:12:32  36 Off",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks MKR for quick solution, +1. Till the point of `TimeInterVal` creation, there weren't issues although in `summarise` it produced `NA`s too often, tried handling those but to avail hard luck

Comment: @KeyshovBorate Just change the `summarise` as `summarise(TimeInterVal = sum(TimeInterVal, na.rm = TRUE))`

Answer (score 2):

using base R:

```
df$Time=as.POSIXct(df$Time,,"%H:%M:%S")

stack(by(df,df$Cat,function(x)sum(c(0,diff(x$Time))*(x$Toggle=="Off"))))

  values ind
1      1 26R
2     21  36
3      0  80
4      0  95
5     12  99
```