# R: How to calculate the time difference of two variables that are in different rows yet belong to the same userId?

Tags: r, time, difference

I am stuck with a question that I can best illustrate through an example dataset:

```
> head(posts, 11)
     userId       postId      post.time    post.freq
1  JON          100000000000  2016-12-06         1
2  JOSH         100000000001  2017-04-29         1
3  JIMBO        100000000002  2018-08-24         1
4  JAMIE        100000000003  2017-01-29         1
5  JANETTE      100000000004  2018-01-17         1
6  BEN          100000000005  2017-05-03         6
7  BEN          100000000006  2017-01-21         6
8  BEN          100000000007  2017-01-24         6
9  BEN          100000000008  2017-01-23         6
10 BEN          100000000009  2017-01-22         6
11 BEN          100000000010  2018-07-03         6
```

In this dataset, **I want to calculate the time difference between two posts for the same userId**. For example, user "BEN" has 6 posts (as post.freq indicates), his first post was created at 2017-01-21, while his second one was created at 2017-01-22; the time difference between these two is 1 day. For "BEN" the time difference between his second and third post would be 1 day again (2017-01-22 and 2017-01-23) and so on; while the time difference of his zeroth and first post is NA.

The result should be something like this:

```
> head(posts, 11)
     userId       postId      post.time    post.freq    post.timediff
1  JON          100000000000  2016-12-06         1          NA
2  JOSH         100000000001  2017-04-29         1          NA
3  JIMBO        100000000002  2018-08-24         1          NA
4  JAMIE        100000000003  2017-01-29         1          NA
5  JANETTE      100000000004  2018-01-17         1          NA      
6  BEN          100000000005  2017-05-03         6          99
7  BEN          100000000006  2017-01-21         6          NA
8  BEN          100000000007  2017-01-24         6          1
9  BEN          100000000008  2017-01-23         6          1
10 BEN          100000000009  2017-01-22         6          1
11 BEN          100000000010  2018-07-03         6          304
```

I couldn't figure out how to do this. Could anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32999460/how-to-calculate-time-difference-with-previous-row-of-a-data-frame-by-group

Comment: This helped a lot! Thank you for the heads up